# Can tcolorbox enhanced boxes be combined with TikZ externalisation and save boxes? If so, how? If not, what's the best workaround?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, boxes, tcolorbox, tikz-external

I am getting the following compilation error when combining TikZ-enhanced boxes from **tcolorbox** with TikZ's externalisation:

```
! Argument of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par 
l.27 }
```

Is this error expected? If so, why and can it be avoided except by disabling externalisation for the box? If not, why is it occurring and can it be avoided except by disabling externalisation for the box?

Not using `skins` and `enhanced` avoids the error. Commenting `\tikzexternalenable` avoids the error. Using a different kind of box here (e.g. an `\efbox`) avoids the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzexternaldisable
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,skins}
\NewTColorBox{gwybodaeth}{ O {\linewidth} m O {} }
{
  enhanced,
  colframe=blue,
  colback=blue!5,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,
  halign title=center,
  title={#2},
  width=#1,
  #3,
}
\begin{document}
\tikzexternalenable
\newsavebox{\argan}
\sbox{\argan}{%
  \begin{gwybodaeth}{Title}
      For example, cabbages or kings.
      Or sealing wax and things.
  \end{gwybodaeth}%
}
\usebox{\argan}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to get this up and running except to disable the externalization temporarily (as mentioned in your question).

The reason is that the externalization library has to scan for the entire picture environment such that it knows which parts are to be replaced by an external picture. To this end, it starts a low-level token search for `\end{tikzpicture}`. This search fails because there is no suitable `\end{tikzpicture}` (per construction).

Making the external lib aware of `tcolorbox` would be a feature request.

Comment: But externalisation works in the case of a `tcolorbox` which is not saved, right? I'd like to understand a bit better: right now, your answer makes it sound like an inevitable conflict between TikZ's `external` library and **tcolorbox**'s `tcolorbox`. But that doesn't explain why it works in the standard case when the box is not saved, and the manual actually recommends using TikZ's externalisation. Would you mind clarifying the role of the save box in the failure?

Comment: I referred to your minimal example only. From what I understand, `\begin{gwybodaeth}` eventually calls `\begin{tikzpicture}` and the associated `\end` statement eventually calls `\end{tikzpicture}`. This construction is incompatible.

Comment: The external lib assumes that it can make is low-level token scan to find the ending `\end{tikzpicture}`. It will not expand any macro while it scans for these tokens. That means: it is generally supported to embed a `tikzpicture` into macro (packages) --- as long as the `\end{tikzpicture}` can be reached without expanding macros on its way.